# listObject equivelent in Azure using php sdk

Tags: php, azure

I am new to Azure and i'm trying to list all objects within a blob with an extension of .json
I can do this easily in AWS and it works perfectly. I've been trying to find an equivalent command in Azure.
Here is what i've tried. It only returns the first .json file.
I need to list all the .json files in all folders ( I know they are not really folders but hopefully people understand what i'm trying to do )

```
$containerName = 'calls';
$result = $blobClient->listBlobs($containerName, $listBlobsOptions);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $keyname = $result['keyname'];
      echo "\n Key name is ".$keyname; // I can see the keyname
    if (strpos($keyname, 'meta-data.json') !== false) {
        $id = $result['id'];
        echo "\n" . $count;
    $blobUrl = $keyname; // I get the blob url returned but its only ever the first level
     $metadata = file_get_contents($blobUrl); // tried to get the file.. no success , another issue to address later
    echo $metadata;
   
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to list blobs in a folder by using azure php SDK:

```php
// List blobs.

    $key = 'keyname';
    $blobListOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
    $blobListOptions->setPrefix($key);

    $blobList = $blobRestProxy->listBlobs($blobContainer, $blobListOptions);

    foreach($blobList->getBlobPrefixes() as $key => $blob) {
        echo "BlobPrefix ".$key.": \t".$blob->getName()."\n";
    }

    foreach($blobList->getBlobs() as $key => $blob) {
        echo "Blob ".$key.": \t".$blob->getName()."\t(".$blob->getUrl().")\n";
    }
```

Thanks to Microsoft for providing more information on Azure PHP SDKs in GitHub [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php#list-blobs-in-a-container).

Comment: Thanks, it gave me the first record only . i can within my 'calls' container i can see

Comment: Thanks, it gave me the first record only . within my 'calls' container i can see
2022 clicking on that i get 08 and then 15, 16, 17 if i click on 17 i get 10-01-46 and inside that is 'myblobs' whch contains 'myblobs-manifest.json'
That is the depth of records i need to transit to get the .json files i wish to read.
I need to read 180 million records and process each .json file.